# Sequence contains more than one matching element on schema update

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I´m using ef-core inheritance like this:

```
public abstract class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public PersonType PersonType { get; set; }
    public int PersonTypeId { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
}

public class Daughter : Person
{
    public double Weigth { get; set; }
    public DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Son : Person
{
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime GraduationDate { get; set; }
}

public class SingleSon : Son
{
}

public class SonWithDaughter : Son
{
    public int Daughter { get; set; }
    public Daughter Daughter { get; set; }
}
```

In DbContext:

```
    public DbSet<PersonType> PersonTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Daughter> Daughters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SingleSon> SingleSons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SonWithDaughter> SonWithDaughters { get; set; }
```

When I update sql server database (dotnet ef database update) it throws a

> System.InvalidOperationException, Sequence contains more than one
>   matching element

Any ideas about how to solve this?

UPDATE

[ef migrations console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBFRG.jpg)

Comment: We need to see the code that generated this error in addition to the models.

Comment: @Amy the error generates when adding a migration from console (dotnet ef...) updated the question with output

Comment: It's now called EntityFrameworkCore and bears the version 1.0. The name EF7 isn't used anymore and shouldn't be used anymore, because people confuse it for a new version of the legeacy framework but its a complete new rewrite and incompatible with the old EF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is issue [#5894](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5894). It will be fixed in version 1.0.1. Until that's released, you can use [the nightly feed](https://dotnet.myget.org/gallery/aspnetcore-patch).